# "Type" of symbolic constants?

Tags: c

1. When is it appropriate to include a type conversion in a symbolic constant/macro, like this:

   ```
   #define MIN_BUF_SIZE ((size_t) 256)
   ```

   Is it a good way to make it behave more like a real variable, with type checking?
2. When is it appropriate to use the `L` or `U` (or `LL`) suffixes:

   ```
   #define NBULLETS 8U
   #define SEEK_TO 150L
   ```

Comment: Just remember that macros are just copy + paste. So it'll take whatever type the context makes it take.

Comment: If the casting is necessary where the macro is placed then you would have the need to add the casting anytime you placed the macro. Doing it the way you propose it propably saves you typing (and perhaps some debugging ;-)).

Comment: Never mind the "behave more like a real variable". The literal value `256` alone would have a type too, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it any time the default type isn't appropriate.  That's it.

Answer (score 4):

Typing a constant can be important at places where the automatic conversions are not applied, in particular functions with variable argument list

```
printf("my size is %zu\n", MIN_BUF_SIZE);
```

could easily crash when the width of `int` and `size_t` are different and you wouldn't do the cast.

But your macro leaves room for improvement. I'd do that as

```
#define MIN_BUF_SIZE ((size_t)+256U)
```

(see the little `+` sign, there?)

When given like that the macro still can be used in preprocessor expressions (with `#if`). This is because in the preprocessor the `(size_t)` evaluates to `0` and thus the result is an unsigned `256` there, too.

Comment: I like your first example.  `gcc` and `clang` (and probably others) will warn about mismatched format/argument pairs these days, though.

Comment: Warnings are often ignored, and won't save you from undefined behaviour on platforms where they're different (e.g. 64-bit platforms with 32-bit ints).  Defining the constant so the behaviour is always correct seems good to me.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is just token pasting preprocessor.

Whatever you write in `#define` it will replace with the replacement text before compilation.

So either way is correct

```
#define A a

int main
{
 int A; // A will be replaced by a
}
```

There are many variations in `#define` like [variadic macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) or [multiline macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Multiline-Macro-Symbols.html)

But the main aim of `#define` is the only one explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly indicating the types in a constant was more relevant in Kernighan and Richie C (before ANSI/Standard C and its function prototypes came along).

Function prototypes like `double fabs(double value);` now allow the compiler to generate proper type conversions when needed.

You still want to explicitly indicate the constant sizes in some cases. The examples that come to my mind right now are bit masks:

- `#define VALUE_1 ((short) -1)` might be 16 bits long while `#define VALUE_2 ((char) -1)` might be 8. Therefore, given a `long x`, `x & VALUE_1` and `x & VALUE_2`would give very different results.

  - This would also be the case for the L or LL suffixes: the constants would use different numbers of bits.

Comment: Given a `long x`, `VALUE_1` and `VALUE_2` will be promoted and sign extended, so you should get the same results.

Comment: Carl, you're right. So much for contrived examples off the top of the head  :-/

Comment: @Luis Pretend you assumed that `char` was unsigned in the implementation under discussion. ;)